# Can we pass event name as props in react?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-dom

Hi I am new to react and I am trying to create a component where we can pass event name(onclick, onChange etc.) as props. So the component can be customize in an event way as well. Is it possible?

```
<Input  {this.props.eventName} = {this.props.name} />
```

This I want to do. Is it possible?

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. It's possible, but why?

Comment: I want to send the event name from parent component so the component can use the passed event. Suppose I send eventName = onClick. When I use the same component different place So want onChnage event. So simply I can pass eventName = onChange.

Comment: Why not just do `onClick={...}` and `onChange={...}`? Or spread the props to the child component: `{...this.props}`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React: How to listen to child component events](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28887570/react-how-to-listen-to-child-component-events)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639534/pass-props-to-parent-component-in-react-js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to achieve something similar to this -

One problem is that you must pass only supported events to the element type.
e.g in case of **button** `onClick` and other events supported by **button**.

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  
  render() {
    return(
       <ChildComponent
        evtName = 'onClick' 
        evtHandler={ () => { console.log("event called!");}}
       />
    )
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
     return React.createElement(
        'button',
        { [this.props.evtName] : this.props.evtHandler },
        'Click me'
      );  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: That's the way to do it, but it doesn't make sense. Does it?

Comment: @loelsonk you are right. But this is what OP wants. This is just a hacky way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example how to pass an `event` from parent Component to Child - by having result in Parent Component.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  //constructor, other methods, etc...

  // We call our event update
  update(stuff) {
    console.log(stuff);
  }
}
```

We pass in ParentComponent's render method a `ChildComponent` with props `onClick`(you can name it whatever you want).

```
<ChildComponent
  onClick={this.update.bind(this)}
/>
```

Now, ChildComponent. To access our props `onClick`, we just use `this.props.onClick`. Our argument is just `hello`, you can pass as many arguments you want.

```
<button onClick={ (e) => this.props.onClick('hello') }>
  Action
</button>
```

Here is working example:

```js
class Parent extends React.Component {
  
  update(stuff) {
    console.log(e, stuff);
  }
  
  render() {
    return(
       <ChildComponent
        onClick={this.update.bind(this)} />
    )
  }
}

class ChildComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      <button onClick={ (e) => this.props.onClick('hello') }> Action</button>
      </div> 
    )
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <Parent />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Here you are passing the method that has to be called on onClick event. Thats fine however I want to make event dynamic. Like here if you want to change event to onChange means you have to change in the child component. But I dont want to do that I just want to pass it as props. Hope I made my point.

Comment: @suyesh You pass it as props. `<ChildComponent onClick={that's it}`. And you access it via the same prop `this.props.onClick`. You can call it whatever you want like so: `<ChildComponent myAction={/* function to call */}` the prop will be accessible via `this.props.myAction`.

Comment: Ok I get your point. In my opinion it is not possible, because how you would know what prop name you should call inside `ChildComponent`, you can pass it as another prop, but you still need to have some hardcoded information.I think you ran into classic [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should do it as simple as you can, it will be easier to maintain later on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, just pass the `event` and it's `handler` as props. I didn't see the use case just considering the event name.

See the below example of reusing the same element with different events.

```js
class Input extends React.Component {
  render(){
    const {} = this.props;
    return (
      <input {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Input name="onClick" onClick={(e) => console.log(e.target.name)}/>
        <Input name="onChange" onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.name)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```